# Is proxy useless when connected to VPN?

Tags: vpn, proxy, torrent

Suppose one is permanently connected to a trusted VPN.

Further let's suppose the primary objective is torrenting solely.

Is there a point to go further, in particular for a proxy?

I ask on behalf of reading mixed information, e.g. for Transmission client:

> Proxies don't work, and Transmission Project decided long ago not to give false hope to users (or plain lies, like others do).
>   From a technical point of view, the traffic handled by a bittorrent client is not the kind of traffic you can route through a proxy, not even a Socks5 proxy.
>   The only thing that works is external to the application: a VPN, and also application level routing (which AFAIK is only available on Linux).

[Source of citation](https://web.archive.org/web/20150614043455/http://sourceforge.net/p/trqtw/feature-requests/21/#3807)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your VPN is trusted and secure enough, I don't see any further benefits from using proxy, or another VPN inside your VPN. This would complicate your setup (setting up proxy everywhere), slow down your connectivity, and add an extra point of failure - for example, the proxy could be hijacked to return malicious content.